# Uploading a github branch from cocoaPod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to upload a branch of restkit from my PodFile (CocoaPod), I don't know if I'm using the right syntax :

```
pod 'RestKit' , :git => 'https://github.com/nhenin/RestKit.git'
```

It's not working anyway, I've this error :

````
### Error

```
undefined method `top_level_parent' for nil:NilClass
/Librar
````